# How to build next.js app with custom server for production

Tags: next.js

I have created a next.js app in there I have a custom server dir. I am using koa.js as my custom server. It works fine on development but, when I build the app, the api routes show 404 not found error. Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "dogs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.7.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.22.17",
    "npm": "please-use-yarn"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./server/index.js",
    "ngrok": "ngrok http 3000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prettier": "prettier --write .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@fireworks-js/preact": "^2.10.1",
    "@koa/cors": "^4.0.0",
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@react-email/button": "^0.0.6",
    "@react-email/container": "^0.0.7-canary.1",
    "@react-email/head": "^0.0.4",
    "@react-email/hr": "^0.0.4",
    "@react-email/html": "^0.0.4",
    "@react-email/img": "^0.0.4",
    "@react-email/link": "^0.0.4",
    "@react-email/preview": "^0.0.5",
    "@react-email/render": "^0.0.6",
    "@react-email/section": "^0.0.7-canary.1",
    "@react-email/text": "^0.0.4",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "TagCloud": "^2.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1300.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "daisyui": "^2.47.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "framer-motion": "^9.0.1",
    "gsap": "^3.11.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.14.1",
    "koa-body": "^6.0.1",
    "koa-cache-control": "^2.0.0",
    "koa-combine-routers": "^4.0.2",
    "koa-conditional-get": "^3.0.0",
    "koa-cookie": "^1.0.0",
    "koa-etag": "^4.0.0",
    "koa-mongo": "^1.9.3",
    "koa-multer": "^1.0.2",
    "koa-router": "^12.0.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.2.0",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "koa-static-cache": "^5.1.4",
    "mongodb": "^4.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "primereact": "^8.7.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.3.4",
    "react-particles": "^2.8.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.0",
    "react-tsparticles": "^2.8.0",
    "split-type": "^0.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "tsparticles": "^2.8.0",
    "tsparticles-engine": "^2.8.0",
    "tsparticles-preset-fireworks": "^2.8.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.2",
    "ngrok": "^4.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5"
  }
}
```

Below is my server code

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import next from 'next';
import Koa from 'koa';
import Router from 'koa-router';
import UserRouter from './routes/user';
import DataRouter from './routes/data';
import EmailRouter from './routes/emails';
import MongoClientConnection from './db';
import cookie from 'koa-cookie';

dotenv.config();

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

// Initialize NextJs instance and expose request handler
const app = next({ dev });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

(async () => {
  try {
    await app.prepare();
    router.get('/custom-page', async (ctx) => {
      await app.render(ctx.req, ctx.res, '/', ctx.query);
      ctx.respond = false;
    });
    const db = await MongoClientConnection.Get();
    server.context.db = db;
    const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
      await handler(ctx.req, ctx.res);
      ctx.respond = false;
      ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
    };
    router.get('/_next/webpack-hmr', handleRequest); // Webpack content is clear
    router.get('(.*)', async (ctx) => {
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    });

    server.use(cookie());
    server.use(UserRouter.routes()).use(UserRouter.allowedMethods());
    server.use(DataRouter.routes()).use(DataRouter.allowedMethods());
    server.use(EmailRouter.routes()).use(EmailRouter.allowedMethods());
    server.use(router.routes());
    server.listen(port, (_) => console.log(`App running on port ${port}`));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit();
  }
})();
```

How can I build my next.js app so my api routes work on production?